# About the connection of $L^2$-convergence and convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $(T_{1,n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(T_{2,n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ two sequences of real valued random variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{A},P)$. Suppose that

$\|T_{1,n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 1$,
$\|T_{2,n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 1$ and
$\|T_{1,n}-T_{2,n}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$.

Suppose further that $T\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{A},P)$ with continuous distribution function and $T_{1,n}\xrightarrow{d} T$ (convergence in distribution).
Does it hold that $T_{2,n}\xrightarrow{d} T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually just need that $T_{1,n}-T_{2,n}$ converges to $0$ in probability. We use portmanteau theorem.

Let $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a uniformly continuous bounded function. Then:
$$|E(f(T_{2,n}))-E(f(T))|\leqslant |E(f(T_{2,n}))-E(f(T_{1,n}))|+|E(f(T_{1,n}))-E(f(T))|,$$
and if $\varepsilon$ is fixed, and $\delta$ the corresponding number in the definition of uniform continuity,
\begin{align}|E(f(T_{2,n}))-E(f(T_{1,n}))|&\leqslant\int_{\{|T_{1,n}-T_{2,n}|>\delta\}}|E(f(T_{2,n}))-E(f(T_{1,n}))|d\mu\\
&+\int_{\{|T_{1,n}-T_{2,n}|\leqslant\delta\}}|E(f(T_{2,n}))-E(f(T_{1,n}))|d\mu\\
&\leqslant 2\sup |f|\cdot \mu\{|T_{1,n}-T_{2,n}|>\delta\}+\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer!